# Compressing Base64 string through LZString gives SyntaxErrors

Tags: javascript, base64

https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/guide.html

I have some Base64 data url strings which need to be compressed into shorter strings. I have downloaded the LZString library and tried to use `Base64String.compress(base64)` and `Base64String.decompress(compressedBase64)` as demonstrated in above official guide.

While the data urls are used for displaying images in offline page, the page is expected to be in compressed size, so each string has to be decompressed within the offline page. Here is a simplified code sample:

```
var compressed = Base64String.compress(dataUrl);
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = "var dataUrl = Base64String.decompress(" + compressed + ");";
offlineHtml.querySelector("body").appendChild(script);
```

However, when I download the page and open it, it shows various forms of SyntaxErrors occurred, including `missing ) after argument list` `Invalid or unexpected token` `Unexpected identifiers`. It seems that the  string is compressed in a way that creates problematic syntax. Is there any solution, or any other suitable library for base64 string compression?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly with that dynamically generated `<script>` tag? I presume that `compressed` is not a valid JavaScript expression and, certainly, JavaScript code is not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to concatenate to create a string containing valid Javascript syntax, save the compressed string somewhere *else* from which *static* Javascript can retrieve and parse it. You could use `<script type="application/json">`, or an invisible textarea, or a data attribute:

```
const compressed = Base64String.compress(dataUrl);
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.dataset.compressed = compressed;
script.textContent = `
  var dataUrl = Base64String.decompress(document.currentScript.dataset.compressed);
`;
offlineHtml.querySelector("body").appendChild(script);
```

(or, preferably, rather than writing the Javascript inline like that, attach a `src` to the script tag instead, which contains the same content)

Comment: Thanks for your ans. The image data URLs can be compressed and decompressed successfully into shorter strings (I have tested through `document.currentScript.dataset.compressed.length`). However, the size of the whole html file is larger than without compression... Is it normal for compressing base64 url strings?

Comment: If the image is extremely tiny, or if it's already compact enough such that it can only barely be compressed further, then the overhead of the code above may not be enough to surpass the miniscule filesize improvement of the compressed string.